# Почему статические переменные в многопоточке это всегда проблемы?

Tags: java, многопоточность, static

Может кто-то объяснить простыми словами почему статические переменные в многопоточке это всегда проблемы? Может какие-то примеры привести. Я сейчас изучаю этот вопрос, читаю различные источники, но не могу понять в чем проблема то?

Comment: И что именно непонятно с этой проблемой?  Объясните на каком-либо изученном вами примере.

Comment: Вот поэтому и проблемы, что с ходу и не понятно. А вот как станет понятно, тогда можно и статические в многопоточке начинать использовать. Но вряд-ли уже захочется.

Answer (score 2):

Многопоточное программирование заключается в том, что разные потоки вне зависимости друг от друга получают доступ к неким разделяемым переменным. При этом, если никак не ограничивать их поочередный доступ, может возникнуть проблема связанная с перезаписью и неактуальным значением поля.

Статические переменные подразумевают то, что доступ к ним осуществляется через класс, а не через отдельный объект, тем более статические переменные общие для всех объектов этого класса, а значит это и то самое узкое место с разделяемыми данными.

Если Вы обращаетесь к статической переменной с целью ее чтения, то в этом нет никакой проблемы. Многопоточность с `final` переменными работает прекрасно.

Если же Вы записываете что-то в эту переменную, то должны использовать все необходимые конструкции Java, такие как `synchronized` методы или `synchronized` блоки.

Старайтесь избегать статических переменных, если их использование не обязательно.